# How to use a LIKE in sp_executesql? I can't construct the statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to use a LIKE in sp_executesql but I can't construct the statement,
I receive errors, this is a simple example just to show the case:

```
SELECT @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement +    
   (CASE @SearchType  
    WHEN 'L' THEN  
      + N' AND aa.Location = COALESCE(@SearchCriteria, '''') '
    WHEN 'M' THEN
 + N' AND aa.ManufactureName LIKE COALESCE(@SearchCriteria, '''') '
    WHEN 'P' THEN  
      + N' AND OH.PONumber = COALESCE(@SearchCriteria, '''')'
   END)
```

Comment: what errors are you receiving..

Comment: This looks like a "concerning" piece of code design ripe and ready to be injected. Look at using stored procedures as your starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Think about write **procedure** not query.

Answer (score 1):

remove the plus sign after THEN

```
WHEN 'x' THEN  N'some X'
```

string concatenation is performed by the plus sign in the first line, and the CASE expression just holds the second operand.

Answer (score 0):

As devio said, yo need to remove the plus sign after the `THEN` clause. Besides, if `@SearchCriteria` is a parameter that you receive like `@SearchType`, then you also need to concatenate his value and not use it inside the statement you are constructing. Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement +    
   (CASE @SearchType  
    WHEN 'L' THEN  
       N' AND aa.Location = COALESCE('''+@SearchCriteria+''', '''') '
    WHEN 'M' THEN
  N' AND aa.ManufactureName LIKE COALESCE(''%'+@SearchCriteria+'%'', '''') '
    WHEN 'P' THEN  
       N' AND OH.PONumber = COALESCE('''+@SearchCriteria+''', '''')'
   END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
(
   (@SearchType = 'L'
      AND aa.Location = @SearchCriteria)
   OR (@SearchType = 'M'
      AND aa.ManufactureName LIKE REPLACE(@SearchCriteria, '%', '[%]') + '%')
   OR (@SearchType = 'P'
      AND OH.PONumber = @SearchCriteria)
)
```